# Pascal > C# Draw raw pixel data to picture box issue

Tags: c#, winforms, delphi, bitmap

In Delphi 7 I am able to do this using an Image Component and that's all fine and dandy but I am trying to convert this same functionality over to C# and am having some issues

```
procedure TMain_Form.Load_Pallete_WPN(FileName: string);
var
  MOMO_Fs: TFileStream;
  i, ii, iii: integer;
begin
  MOMO_Fs := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
  MOMO_Fs.Position := $82D80;
  MOMO_Fs.Read(RGBA, $400);

  iii := 0;
  for i := 0 to 15 do
  begin
    for ii := 0 to 15 do
    begin
      Pallet_Preview.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[ii, i] :=
        RGB(RGBA[iii].b, RGBA[iii].G, RGBA[iii].R);
      inc(iii);
    end;
  end;

  MOMO_Fs.Free;
end;
```

[image]

This is the working result in pascal just to be clear.
Now when i try to implement this behaviour in C# I have tried the following

```
public struct TRGBA_Obj
{

    public byte b;
    public byte g;
    public byte r;
    public byte a;

}


       public TRGBA_Obj[] RGBA = new TRGBA_Obj[255];
       public string fp;


    public void Load_Pallette(string filepath)
    {
        int i, ii, iii;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);



            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(256, 256);



        fs.Seek(0x82D80, SeekOrigin.Begin); // this is where the palette is  


        for (int x = 0; x < RGBA.Length; x++)
        {
            RGBA[x].r = br.ReadByte();
            RGBA[x].g = br.ReadByte();
            RGBA[x].b = br.ReadByte();
            RGBA[x].a = br.ReadByte();


               // this just dumps the color values to a list view for ref
            LV_COLOR_PALETTE.Items.Add(x.ToString());
            LV_COLOR_PALETTE.Items[x].SubItems.Add(RGBA[x].r.ToString());
            LV_COLOR_PALETTE.Items[x].SubItems.Add(RGBA[x].g.ToString());
            LV_COLOR_PALETTE.Items[x].SubItems.Add(RGBA[x].b.ToString());
            LV_COLOR_PALETTE.Items[x].SubItems.Add(RGBA[x].a.ToString());

        }

        iii = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
            {
               bmp.SetPixel(j, y, Color.FromArgb(RGBA[iii].a, RGBA[iii].r, RGBA[iii].g, RGBA[iii].b));

                iii++;   
            }
        }



        random_box.Image = bmp;


        fs.Close();
        br.Close();
```

My results with the pascal example works as intended, as it is only a 256 pixel palette the C# drawn image is extremely small I have tried all the zoom/stretch options for the picturebox, if i change bmp's height & width from 256/256 to lower values the image size increases but look's nothing like the working delphi example, any tips? haha

Answer (score 1):

The pascal code you've shown does not produces the image you've shown. The image is probably 256 x 256 pixels, but you only address up to 15 x 15 pixels. If you would pay attention to formatting your code properly it would be easy to spot, so I formatted it for you.

Your pallette has 256 colors and obviously the image you've shown, shows each color as a 16 x 16 pixel block. You need to add two more loops to address these blocks.

Then to address the pixels in the image you need to calculate `block * 16 + pixwithinblock` both for horizontal and vertical.

The pascal code could look like this:

```
procedure TForm6.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x, y: integer; // block indexes
  i, ii, // pixels within a block
  iii: integer; // palette index
begin
  iii := 0;
  for y := 0 to 15 do
  begin
    for x := 0 to 15 do
    begin
      for i := 0 to 15 do
      begin
        for ii := 0 to 15 do
        begin
          Image1.Canvas.Pixels[x * 16 + ii, y * 16 + i] :=
            RGB(RGBA[iii].rgbBlue, RGBA[iii].rgbGreen, RGBA[iii].rgbRed);
        end;
      end;
      inc(iii);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Note that the color index changes when the block index changes.

Alternatively, you could address the pixels as 0 .. 255 horizontally and vertically and calculate the color index as follows:

```
procedure TForm6.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, ii, iii: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 255 do
    for ii := 0 to 255 do
    begin
      iii := (i div 16) * 16 + (ii div 16);
      Image1.Canvas.Pixels[ii, i] :=
        RGB(RGBA[iii].rgbBlue, RGBA[iii].rgbGreen, RGBA[iii].rgbRed);
    end;
end;
```

I'm not a C# programmer, but it seems you have got the conversion correctly, so I'm sure you can also convert this modified pascal code.